# How to perform a conditional assignment on each element of the vector

Tags: function, matlab, vector

I have a function like this:

> y=-2     with x<=0
>   y=-2+3x^2    with 0=1

I need to compute this function on each element of the 1D matrix, without using a loop.

I thought it was possibile defining a function like this one:

```
function y= foo(x)

if x<=0
    y=-2;
elseif x>=1
    y=1;
else
    y= -2+3*x.^2;
end

end
```

But this just produces a single result, how to operate on all elements? I know the . operator, but how to access the single element inside an if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function b = helper(s)
  if s<=0
    b=-2;
  elseif s>=1
    b=1;
  else
    b= -2+3*s^2;
  end
end
```

Then simply call

```
arrayfun(@helper, x)
```

to produce the behaviour you want of your function `foo`.

Comment: It says: "Error using helper (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.".

Comment: @Ramy Yeah, there was an `@` missing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which doesn't need `arrayfun()` would be to multiply by the conditions:

```
y = -2*(x <= 0) + (-2+3*x.^2).*(x < 1).*(x > 0) + (x >= 1)
```

which you could also make a function. This will accept vector inputs for `x` e.g.

```
x = [1 4 0 -1 0.5];
y = -2*(x <= 0) + (-2+3*x.^2).*(x < 1).*(x > 0) + (x >= 1)
```

outputs

```
y =

   1.0000   1.0000  -2.0000  -2.0000  -1.2500
```